# Sum values from different table using LEFT JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, regex, left-join

I'm trying to sum all `coins` from `m_z_analytics` when `site` have number same as `id` from `m_b_browsing_live` (see result below).

Tables:

```
m_z_analytics

id|site_id|coins|
 1|      1| 0.01|
 2|      2|  0.1|
 3|      1| 0.08|
 4|      2|  0.1|
 3|      3|  0.2|


m_b_browsing_live

id| cpc|
 1|0.09|
 2| 0.1|
 3| 0.5|
```

The final result should be: **0.38** 
*(0.09 + 0.1 + 0.09 + 0.1)*

I've tried so far:

```
SELECT SUM(a.coins) AS money FROM m_z_analytics a
LEFT JOIN m_b_browsing_live b ON b.id=a.site_id
WHERE CONCAT(',', `a.site_id`, ',') REGEXP ',(1|2),'
```

Comment: Regex does not perform arithmetic operations. You'll need something else.

Comment: @emsimpson92 I have 50 different tables connected to this code. I've tried with FIND_IN_SET but it's not what i'm looking for.

Comment: Your question is not clear. You state that you need sum of all `coins` from `m_z_analytics` but your SQL shows `SELECT SUM(a.cpc) AS coins FROM m_b_browsing_live a` which is SUM of all `cpc` from `m_b_browsing_live`. Please clarify your question.

Comment: @JenyaG Sure, I already updated it.

Comment: Please explain the left join - if you are not using the data from m_z_analytics, then why not use an inner join. What has this got to do with regular expressions? PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your final result of 0.29 will be only if you select records with `site_id = 1` or `site_id = 2`, thats probably why you used `REGEX` stuff there.

Your question implies that you have no restrictions for `site_id` being 1 or 2 ONLY, it implies that as long as `site_id` is matching `id` column SUM should be calculated, so correct answer will be 0.49.

Anyways, I've tried best to decipher what you were trying to do, so I'll give you two answers:

Your example query (wrong result of 0.29) will be correctly written as:

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM(a.coins),2) AS money FROM m_z_analytics a
LEFT JOIN m_b_browsing_live b ON b.id=a.site_id
WHERE a.site_id IN(1,2);
```

Answer to your *question* correctly (result = 0.49) it will be:

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM(a.coins),2) AS money FROM m_z_analytics a
LEFT JOIN m_b_browsing_live b ON b.id = a.site_id;
```

Or even without `LEFT JOIN` syntax this is equivalent:

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM(a.coins),2) AS money FROM m_z_analytics a, 
m_b_browsing_live b WHERE b.id = a.site_id;
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/56315/9)

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you!